# Envers : JPA : Audit table does not store revisions of an entity (saving Same entity Multiple times)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am trying to save an entity which updates(for example: status column gets updated at each stage) multiple times in method. All these revisions are needed to be reflected in its audit table as well.

But, only the latest update alone is reflected in the audit table and rest of the updates are not.

Given ,
I have entity name with @Audited, service class with @Service, EntityRepository extends JPARepository.
I dont want to use ValidityAuditStrategy as it might change the schema/columns of each table.

Any inputs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.